# mvn: command not found though the M2_home is set

Tags: github, maven-3

I'm trying to run some automation tests using a workflow file in a linux server. I have installed maven in the server and this is what appears for the mvn -version.

```
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 17.0.10, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-1055-aws", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I have setup the M2_home using the .bashrc and this is how it is done.

```
JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64"
export JAVA_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
M2_HOME="/usr/share/maven"
export M2_HOME
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

But when I run the yml file i get an error in the sep which runs the maven command. This is how that looks like

```
  - name: Build Maven
    run: mvn clean install
```

I can't figure out why i get this error when I have already installed and setup the maven variables. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: What do you see if you run a `which mvn`?

Comment: @Aaron - it outputs -> /usr/bin/mvn

Comment: Are you referring to a *github CI workflow* here? if so, your .bashrc file is perhaps not the place to set these things - see for example [Specifying the Java version and architecture](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-java-with-maven#specifying-the-java-version-and-architecture) in the [Building and testing Java with Maven](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-java-with-maven)